# How to implement a .dll in unity code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins, dllimport

I wrote a code in unity to read some data from a measurement plate. Unfortunately the compiler gives the following error out:

```
Assets/Scribts/Initialize.cs(74,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IDevice' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

After some research I found out that unity can't work with .dll's out of .NET languages. Thus you have to put it into a native plugin.

Do you know what to do or if there are some sample projects?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"I wrote a code in unity to read some data from a measurement plate"* What language did you use? If this is C#, you can build managed plugin with it without going native...

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire tutorial on this you can read here: http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/10/11/how-to-write-native-plugins-for-unity/

The summary is:

1) Put the native plugin into the `Assets/Plugins` folder.

2) Define the api in a class, like:

```
[DllImport("TestDLL", EntryPoint = "TestSort")]
public static extern void TestSort(int [] a, int length);
```

There's an example of sqlite here to look at here: https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d

You'll see the C# code is along the lines of the above:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Open ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, out IntPtr db);

[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open_v2", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Open ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, out IntPtr db, int flags, IntPtr zvfs);

[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open_v2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Open(byte[] filename, out IntPtr db, int flags, IntPtr zvfs);

[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open16", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Open16([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string filename, out IntPtr db);

[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_enable_load_extension", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result EnableLoadExtension (IntPtr db, int onoff);
```

...but also notice how many `#ifdef` conditions there are.

Building cross platform native bindings is hard work.

Also note this *only* applies to C/C++ libraries; if you have an existing C# .Net library (eg. NHibernate), the answer is no, you just flat out can't use that DLL; you must get the C# source and recompile it specifically for unity.

Comment: *"you just flat out can't use that DLL; you must get the C# source and recompile it specifically for unity."* Not true. You can. The dll just has to be made with .NET version <=3.5. That's it.

Comment: @Programmer there are no DLLs out there that target 3.5; it's an obsolete and unsupported runtime. That's what I meant when I said 'you must get the C# source and recompile it specifically for unity'. ...but to be fair, yes, 'specifically for unity' == 3.5 runtime.